# Allow selecting a cell while a UISearchController is active

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit

I have a `UICollectionViewController` with a `UISearchController` embedded in the parent `UINavigationController`'s navigation bar. 
I'm using cells which are a custom subclass of `UICollectionViewCell`, containing a single `UIImageView`.

However, while searching, I'm not able to select cells that were found by the search. Selecting/tapping cells works perfectly when the search controller is not active, and I've already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38650462/searching-tableview-cant-select-row) answer without success.

Here's my search setup code:

```
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
searchController.definesPresentationContext = true
searchController.searchBar.keyboardAppearance = .default
searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false

navigationItem.searchController = searchController
navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
```

I'd appreciate any help in resolving this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out after playing around with the `UICollectionView` for a bit.

I was overriding `touchesBegan` as shown below:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    guard !searchController.isActive else { return }
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1) { () -> Void in
        let shrinkTransform = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: 0.9, y: 0.9)
        self.transform = shrinkTransform
    }
}
```

The issue was that I was checking whether the search controller was active BEFORE calling `super.touchesBegan`, which was blocking touches whenever the search controller was active.

Moving the guard statement directly below the `super.touchesBegan` call fixed my issue.

Hope this helps anyone else who happens to experience a similar issue!